# Inserting / Embedding an object into excel using Office Script

Tags: excel, vba, office-scripts

I am currently using Excel VBA (in "Claim.xlsm") to insert / embed an object (generally an .msg file or a .pdf) into my excel worksheet (onyl 1 worksheet in "Claim.xlsm". The same VBA is then used save the file as "Claim.xlsx" and then email it to certain people through Outlook.

I want to convert all this process from VBA to Office Script and Power Automate. The creating a copy as "Claim.xlsx" and email that file to people is working fine (in Power Automate). However, I am unable to inset / embed the object using office script in the excel sheet.

I tried to get my actions recorded in Office Script but it says it can not be recorded. Need help on this particular matter.

Comment: Can you provide the VBA code that you use to do the task?